# Linking SDL in Makefile on mac

Tags: c, macos, makefile, clang, sdl

I'm trying to learn how to use libraries when writing C code on my mac (not using Xcode). My understanding is that on macs, there is the Library/Frameworks folder where you can put common libraries that can be shared across different projects.

My goal at this point is to use the SDL library to open basic window and do nothing else, but I can't figure out how to utilize libraries on my mac. So to be very specific, I just want to have one file of application code that I have written called `main.c` and it will have this boilerplate SDL code:

```
#include "SDL2/SDL.h" // OR #include "SDL.h" (Not sure how the difference in path works)

int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800;
int SCREEN_WIDTH = 600;

int main() {
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
  SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Game", 0, 0, 
  SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_WIDTH, SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN);
  SDL_ShowWindow(window);

  SDL_Event event;
  int running = 1;

  while(running) {
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
      if(event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
        running = 0;
      }
    }

    SDL_Delay( 32 );
  }

  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_Quit();

  return 0;
}
```

I downloaded the development library for mac from the SDL website (https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) and moved the download to the `/Library/Frameworks` folder on my machine, just as SDL instructed. However I don't know what to do in my Makefile for the library to be included and linked and then compiled with my main.c file.

Here are some specifics of my laptop/compiler:

```
MacOS Bug Sur
Version 11.3.1
MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)
Processor: 2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9
Memory: 32 GB 2667 MHz DDR4
Startup Disk: Macintosh HD
Graphics: AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 8 GB
```

```
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Can someone show me what an example of a very simple Makefile would look like to accomplish this goal??

Comment: Assuming you have the SDL libraries installed in the right place (I don't know what this is since I don't use a mac) you can just issue a command like: `gcc main.c -o game -lSDL2`. If you have the libraries installed in a nonstandard location (i.e one gcc is not looking for) you can use the capitol L argument: `gcc main.c -o game -Lpath/to/libraries/folder -lSDL2`

Answer (score 0):

If you work from the command line or with a properly configured IDE, you link (In GCC) with the `-l(library name)` flag. The library you want to link needs to be in some directory like **/usr/lib, /usr/local/lib** or some Libraries folder MacOS might have. If it's not there, then use the -L(path/to/lib/directory) to tell GCC where to find it, and then use `-l(library name)` flag again.

The library name should start with `lib` and either end with a `.a` or `.so` suffix. So if you wish to link to your own SDL2 library build:

```
gcc source.c -o mygame -Llibraries/ -lSDL2
```

Assuming that the library is under `libraries/libSDL2.so` (Numbers in the end don't matter).

Answer (score 0):

## To link SDL with makefile on OSX

Since this is an old post you may have moved on from your question.
That is why I won't spend much time on creating a project for your
scenario. You'll just have to adapt.
[cLion example project](https://github.com/charlesyiu/gametest)

### Install [homebrew](https://brew.sh)

### Install SDL via homebrew

```
$ brew install sdl2 sdl2_image sdl2_mixer sdl2_net sdl2_ttf
```

(you only need sdl2 but the others are useful
if you don't want to install the selected component
just remove it)

### Add makefile

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(game_test C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
# find_package(SDL2_ttf REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(game_test main.c)
target_link_libraries(game_test ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
# target_link_libraries(game_test ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} SDL2_ttf::SDL2_ttf)
```

#### Make it an application (.app) (optional)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(game_test C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
# find_package(SDL2_ttf REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(game_test main.c arial.ttf AppIcon.icns)
set(RESOURCE_FILES arial.ttf AppIcon.icns) # these files go into .app/Contents/Resources/
target_link_libraries(game_test ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
# target_link_libraries(game_test ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} SDL2_ttf::SDL2_ttf)

set(MACOSX_BUNDLE_ICON_FILE AppIcon.icns)
set_target_properties(game_test PROPERTIES MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_IDENTIFIER ch.yiu.Counter RESOURCE "${RESOURCE_FILES}")
# <lastname>.<firstname>.<appname> or <domain>.<appname>
# (domain formatted as com.example instead of example.com)
```

Comment: That's CMake though, not Makefile. There's a difference.

Comment: My bad, I was still new to C at that time.